# How to make a div that take 400px width from right to left

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment, width

I want to make div of width 500px that aligned to the right of my container div. So when I apply width: 500px it expand towards the right side but I want it to expand from right to left.

Comment: `flex-direction: row-reverse;` is what you looking for.

Comment: actually : float on the container itself else  direction, grid,flex from the parent . (direction worked decades ago and still does). Which one have you tried or need ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want a flex-item to be placed at the right and expand from right to left, yoo need to use `flex-direction: row-reverse;` on the flex-container:

```css
div.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}


/* for styling purpose only */
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div.container {
  height: 100vh;
}

div.right {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to set `direction: rtl` on the container. You can also add `direction: ltr` to the inside div of you want that one to have normal flow for items contained in it. (Keyframes added only for visual purposes.)

```css
.container {
  direction: rtl;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 200px;  
}
.box {
  /*direction: ltr;*/
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  animation: 5s grow linear infinite;
}

@keyframes grow {
  from {width:25px};
  to {width: 150px};
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#box{
  float:right;
  width:500px;
  height:100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#holder{
  border:2px solid black;
  width:700px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="holder">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: float is an outdated and now mis-used hack. Its not fory styling purpose. It brings a variaty of different issues. Also the question itself is tagged with flexbox. So no need to to use such a hack.

Comment: @tacoshy float is not outdated nor a hack. It's a CSS feature

Comment: but for styling purpose it is a hack and outdated. You know that float was never intended for that pupose but only for floating images within a paragraph.